# How to route to a specific function in a view from django template?

Tags: django, templates, view

For example I have the following situation where a delete button has to be routed different depending upon who has clicked it, like if he's an admin display a message else go to the delete view. I thought I will place the function to send a message in detail generic view but how to call that function directly from template?

```
{% if user_detail.status == ADMIN %}
   <button class="btn clearfix"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Cannot Delete Admin</button>
{% else %}
   <a href="{% url "members:delete" userid=user_detail.pk %}" class="btn clearfix"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete User</a>
{% endif %}
```

The delete generic view is directly linked to the template, is there to display message in detail view itself before redirecting to the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions to do this, one is to check for staff-status in the View, using one of the [multiple mixins](http://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access.html#staffuserrequiredmixin) already made for this or check if hes a admin some other way and then either return an error message or redirect to one i.e

```
def myview(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(..errormessage-url or view..)
    .. do stuff here for admin users..
```